# UTF-8 not working in live server

Tags: java, windows-server-2012-r2, docx4j

I am new to docx4j. I am creating new .docx file using docx4j. My code works perfectly while deploying project from eclipse to tomcat server. But it does not work on live server. Below is my code:

```
String html = "<html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><title></title>"
                + "</head><body>"
                + "<div><div style='width:100%;display:inline; text-align:right;'>मितिः &nbsp; "
                +new Date()+"</div><div class=\"block p-top-2\" style='display:block; float:left;'>"
                + "च.नं.  &nbsp;"
                + "<span style=\"display: inline !important;\">"+10088+" - "+73 + "/" + 74
                + "</span></div></div></body></html>";
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

AlternativeFormatInputPart afiPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(new PartName("/hw.html"));
afiPart.setBinaryData(html.getBytes());
afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType("text/html"));
Relationship altChunkRel = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(afiPart);
afiPart.registerInContentTypeManager(); 

CTAltChunk ac = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTAltChunk();
ac.setId(altChunkRel.getId() );
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(ac);           

wordMLPackage.getContentTypeManager().addDefaultContentType("html", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
wordMLPackage.save(new File("created_doc.docx"));
```

Below is my screen shot of my local:
[image: Expected format]

Below is my screen shot of my live server
[image: UTF-8 not supported format]

I am using Tomcat and Spring Framework.Project created using maven and deployed on windows server 2012 r2.

Comment: Are the screenshots of the docx open in Word? Open on the respective machines, or both on your local machine?  Maybe different fonts installed?  You are more likely to get an answer if you post the actual docx files somewhere.  Is the Java locale set the same in eclipse and tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this may be the problem:

```
afiPart.setBinaryData(html.getBytes());
```

That will use the platform-default encoding - which could clearly differ between your local machine and your server. I would strongly encourage you to *always* specify the encoding. If you want UTF-8, use:

```
afiPart.setBinaryData(html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```